# C - finding cube root of a negative number with pow function

Tags: c, math

In real world cube root for a negative number should exist:
`cuberoot(-1)=-1`, that means `(-1)*(-1)*(-1)=-1`
or
`cuberoot(-27)=-3`, that means `(-3)*(-3)*(-3)=-27`

But when I calculate cube root of a negative number in C using `pow` function, I get `nan` (not a number)

```
double cuber;
cuber=pow((-27.),(1./3.));
printf("cuber=%f\n",cuber);
```

output: `cuber=nan`

Is there any way to calculate cube root of a negative number in C?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**7.12.7.1 The `cbrt` functions**

**Synopsis**

```
#include <math.h>
double cbrt(double x);
float cbrtf(float x);
long double cbrtl(long double x);
```

**Description**

The `cbrt` functions compute the real cube root of `x`.

---

If you're curious, `pow` can't be used to compute cube roots because one-third is not expressible as a floating-point number.  You're actually asking `pow` to raise `-27.0` to a rational power very nearly equal to 1/3; there is no real result that would be appropriate.

Comment: `pow` can be used to compute cube roots of positive numbers.

Comment: @SteveJessop: `pow` can be used to compute the `0.333333333333333314829616256247390992939472198486328125`th power of a positive number, which is often (but not always) the same as the cube root after rounding.

Comment: It's as close as the C standard guarantees `cbrt` to be (which is no guarantee at all). IEEE 754 might have something else to say, though, if it guarantees the accuracy of `cbrt`.

Comment: @SteveJessop: Right.  I'm not suggesting that you should use `cbrt` for accuracy.  You should use it for speed on some platforms, but the real reason to use it is because it gives you "the answer you want" for negative inputs -- `pow` can't do that, because there is no real 0.333333333333333314829616256247390992939472198486328125th power of a negative number.

Comment: I definitely agree with the last part, the reason the questioner should use it is that it accepts negative inputs. It's not in C89 though, and I suspect not on MSVC, so that's the only possible reason not to use it.

Comment: @SteveJessop: Presumably MSVC will finally get around to adding it, now that it's in C++.

Comment: I suspect `pow`'s problem is that `log(x)` returns a NaN for negative `x`.

Comment: @DanielFischer: No, that's not the issue (though it is closely related).  A C stdlib `pow` cannot be implemented by naively returning `exp(y * log(x))`, as that gets many edge cases wrong.  For example, try `pow(-27.0, -1.0)`.

Comment: @Stephen Canon: thank you! I tried to find cbrt function in C manuals - but nothing. Can you give a reference to that function? thanks!

Comment: Section 7.12.7.1 in the C standard.  The same information can be found in the POSIX or UNIX standards.

Comment: Yes, it has to check for integer exponents if the argument is (finite and) negative. So it could just check for an integer exponent, and if the exponent is not integral calculate `exp(y*log(x))`. I've done a bit of code-searching and it looks like glibc's `pow` does almost that (it calculates `2^(y*log2(x))`, basically, if I'm not entirely misled).

Answer (score 6):

there is. Remember: x^(1/3) = -(-x)^(1/3). So the following should do it:

```
double cubeRoot(double d) {
  if (d < 0.0) {
    return -cubeRoot(-d);
  }
  else {
    return pow(d,1.0/3.0);
  }
}
```

Written without compiling, so there may be syntax errors.

Greetings,
Jost

Comment: this is not as precise as the standard `cbrt()` function

Answer (score 1):

As Stephen Canon answered, to correct function to use in this case is cbrt(). If you don't know the exponent beforehand, you can look into the cpow() function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <complex.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("cube root cbrt: %g\n", cbrt(-27.));
    printf("cube root pow: %g\n", pow(-27., 1./3.));
    double complex a, b, c;
    a = -27.;
    b = 1. / 3;
    c = cpow(a, b);
    printf("cube root cpow: (%g, %g), abs: %g\n", creal(c), cimag(c), cabs(c));
    return 0;
}
```

prints

```
cube root cbrt: -3
cube root pow: -nan
cube root cpow: (1.5, 2.59808), abs: 3
```

Keep in mind the definition of the complex power: cpow(a, b) = cexp(b* clog(a)).

Answer (score 0):

Using Newton's Method:

```py
def cubicroot(num):
  flag = 1
  if num < 0:
    flag = -1
    num = num - num - num
  x0 = num / 2.
  x1 = x0 - (((x0 * x0 * x0) - num) / (3. * x0 * x0))
  while(round(x0) != round(x1)):
    x0 = x1
    x1 = x0 - (((x0 * x0 * x0) - num) / (3. * x0 * x0))
  return x1 * flag

print cubicroot(27)
```