# Math.pow with negative numbers and non-integer powers

Tags: javascript, floating-point, ieee-754, ecmascript-5, ecma262

The ECMAScript specification for `Math.pow` has the following peculiar rule:

> - If x < 0 and x is finite and y is finite and y is not an integer, the result is NaN.

(http://es5.github.com/#x15.8.2.13)

As a result `Math.pow(-8, 1 / 3)` gives `NaN` rather than `-2`

What is the reason for this rule? Is there some sort of broader computer science or IEEEish reason for this rule, or is it just a choice TC39/Eich made once upon a time?

---

#### Update

Thanks to Amadan's exchanges with me, I think I understand the reasoning now. I would like to expand upon our discussion for the sake of posterity.

Let's take the following example: `Math.pow(823543, 1 / 7)` yields `6.999999999999999` although it really should be `7`. This is an inaccuracy introduced by the fact that `1 / 7` must first be converted to a decimal representation `0.14285714285714285`, which is truncated and loses precision. This isn't such a bad problem when we're working with positive numbers because we still get a result that's extremely close to the real result.

However, once we step into the negative world we have a problem. If a JavaScript engine were to try to compute `Math.pow(-823543, 1 / 7)` it would first need to convert `1 / 7` to a decimal, so it would really be computing `Math.pow(-823543, 0.14285714285714285)` which actually *has no real answer*. In this case, it may have to return `NaN` since it couldn't find a real number, even though the real answer should be `-7`. Futhermore, looking for complex numbers which are close to real numbers to make a "best guess" may involve a level of complexity they didn't want to require a JS engine to have in the math arena.

My guess is it is due to the consideration of the loss of precision in floating point numbers that led them to the rule that negative numbers to a non-integer power should always be `NaN` -- basically because a non-integer power is likely to give a complex number as a result of loss of precision, even if it shouldn't, and there may be no good way to recover from it.

With this, I'm fairly satisfied, but I do welcome further information.

Comment: Se also [Math.Pow() is broken](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14367448/) (some comments to some answers discuss the complex-number `Pow` function) and [finding cube root of a negative number with pow function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8493005/) and others. A lot of calculators will happily calculate `(-x)^q` where `-x` is negative and `q` is a non-whole number which _looks_ like it's rational with odd denominator (when fraction is in lowest terms). So IEEE is different from that.

Comment: Also: [Cube root of a negative number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8290804/). This question is asked very frequently with different wordings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume because those circumstances lead the result into complex waters, and ECMAScript is not equipped with imaginary numbers. Specifically, your example should result in something close to `1 + 1.732i`, among other results. (The fact that -2 is also a possible result is besides the point - it is an accident rather than a rule.)

Comment: Huh? There is a real answer. -2. It's fine to give `NaN` if there is no real answer. But if there's a real answer, why not give it to me?

Comment: To be more precise: `Math.pow(8, 1 / 3)` has two complex answers and one real answer. In this case, JavaScript is happy to give me the real answer `2`, even though there are other answers. What's the difference?

Comment: Sorry, I edited later to address your point. For example, `(-8) ^ (4.32)` does not have a convenient real solution; and I suppose that rooting out (heh, heh) the cases that do have a rational solution is outside the scope of the specification.

Comment: Good counter-example. Your answer has helped me to think through it some more, and I think I understand now why it is the case. Fractions must be converted to floating point numbers, and due to limitations in the precision of floats, it'd be easy for a computation to be ever-so-slightly off in such a way that a real became complex and JS had to return NaN rather than a close reasonable result. In this case guessing may be too error-prone. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can use a helper function.

In swift I faced a similar situation. Here is a proposed solution for you:

```
function checkPower(x, y) {
  if (x > 0 || Math.round(y) == y) {
    return Math.pow(x, y)
  } else {
    var r = -1 * Math.pow(-x, y);
    if( Math.pow( r, 1/y) == x) 
      return r;
    else 
      return NaN;
  }
}
```